# how do i combine items from orders for shipping in magento?

Tags: magento

i'm looking at putting multiple items from different orders into the same shipping box.  ideally when i go to ship an order, on the items section for that order all open items for that customer would show up.  i have isolated the code that generates the items to:

app/design/adminhtml/default/mytemplate/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml

and the line of code in that file to:

$_items = $this->getShipment()->getAllItems();

in the function getAllItems i have added the following code:

```
$cust_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$this->getCustomerId());

foreach ($cust_orders as $order) {
    $order_id = $order->getEntityId();
    $cust_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order_id);
    foreach ($cust_items as $cust_item) {
        { help! }
    }
```

i need some help at the help! part.  i'm trying to get the new array ($cust_items) into the array $items properly.  but i can not seem to figure that part out...  its seems that object is getting populated using the getItemsCollection function; something i am doing has gone adrift....

let me know if you have any new ideas. thanks.

Comment: actually after digging around some more, it is apparent that the change needs to be made in the items collection much further down the chain.  and from the item collection is where i would need to load all of the items.  if anyone wants to add their 2cents, i'm listening.  thanks.

Comment: solved! i changed the second getModel to getModel('sales/order_shipment_item') and the filter to 'parent_id; then replaced the help with $items[] = $cust_item; and it looks like i can good to go...  more minor modifications and have yet to test the actual shipping part of it, but this part looks done.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $cust_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$this->getCustomerId());


foreach ($cust_orders as $order) {
    $order_id = $order->getEntityId();
    $cust_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_item')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $order_id);
    foreach ($cust_items as $cust_item) {
        $items[] = $cust_item;
    }
```

some other minor tweaks, and more testing, but i look good to go.

this answer is clearly wrong.... still working on finding a solution.... very confusing to me...